# Is it possible to increase Ceph throughput with multi-port NICs without LACP?

Tags: networking, bonding, ceph

My Ceph cluster consists of 3 rather old servers storage servers, and a Netgear GS724Tv1, which does not appear to support LACP.

I have already set up a separate cluster network and public network, and each storage server has a quad port NIC. Each client also has a dual port NIC. All the NICs are gigabit, as I do not wish to spend several hundred pounds on a personal cluster's networking.

I have been trying to use Linux's interface bonding to increase transfers. By binding to multiple IPs and using alb bonding, I have managed to get an increased raw throughput (measured with `iperf`), but this performance has not carried over to Ceph.

Is it possible to use the multiple ports on the NICs to increase the bandwith between the OSDs and the clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by deleting and recreating the network manager configuration for the bond. It appeared that it had not registered one of the network interfaces as the slave, and so was only sending the traffic through one port.